# UC3843 IC question

Tags: integrated-circuit, dc-dc-converter

This is UC3843 diagram form [TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3843.pdf?ts=1614425815923&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FUC3843%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Dapp-null-null-GPN_EN-cpc-pf-google-tw%2526utm_content%253DUC3843%2526ds_k%253DUC3843%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DCj0KCQiA-OeBBhDiARIsADyBcE7U2s8knDzreiYq1rFOAqQPSRY4vXr8IAMB-RC_sJmO8AC59RwnewQaAr4NEALw_wcB%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds), and I have a question in thus figure. why should add two diodes in the IC,  what's the diode useful?

[image]

Comment: It creates a voltage drop, giving a little margin of error. The same for the Zener afterwards. Use [this file](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/files/z_yahoo/adventures_with_analog/my%20model%20files/UC3842A.zip) to see details of functioning (registration required, to avoid spammers).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I still not get it. Can you give me a example?  why can give a little margin of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two forward polarized diodes, so the voltage drop across both is ~1.4 V. This means that the voltage before them can be ~1.4 V higher, creating a "margin of error" for transients. There's also a resistive divider so it's actually even larger. One reason is to not damage the next stage, which is the comparator. The Zener diode has the same purpose: protecting the input.

Comment: I can understand the voltage drop is ~1.4V. but what is margin of error?  if they don't have two diode what will be happen?

Comment: Margin of error means tolerance. If the expected voltage at the input of the comparator is maximum 1 V, without diodes it will be 2.4 V (discarding the resitor divider). That may not damage the comparator, but it can cause the functionality to behave in a wrong way. For example the peak current can get too high values that can damage the transistor.

Comment: but in the IC it has a zener diode so if the output is large, the zener diode can clamp to 1V, right?

Comment: And before the Zener? There is a 3x attenuation, which means 3 V, with 1.4 V it means 4.4 V. That means a ~50% margin, the peak current can vary 50% above the thershold before clamping starts. That accounts for transient moments such as a capacitor charging, or a step change in the load, etc.

Comment: I mean if the current is too high, the OPA will be saturation, that mean the output of OPA is 6V (in the datasheet), and (6-1.4)*(1/3) > 1, and zener diode will be clamp to 1V. and If no diode in the circuit 6*(1/3)>1 , the result will be the same.
So I still don't understand why you said  giving a margin of error.

Comment: You are talking about steady-state, I am talking about *transients*. Not only the error amp is *not* driven into saturation during normal operation, or even close to it, it's also something to avoid because of the longer time it takes for it to come out of saturation (if it should occur). I gave you a link, were you curious to see what's in it? Granted, it's a behavioural approach, but if you plot the voltage at the error amp output, you'll see that the voltage doesn't vary linearly, it over-/under-shoots when the load is changed, or even as it stabilizes itself.

Comment: What's link I don't see it

Comment: Didn't you see the link in my first comment?

Comment: I see it, thanks

Comment: The two diodes in series are there to guaranty 0% duty ratio when the voltage at the CMP pin drops below \$\approx\$1.4 V and forces the IC to enter kind of rough skip cycle.